# ggplot&ie with parse=T equal symbol problem

Tags: r, parsing, ggplot2, annotate

I need your help. The problem seems to be very simple but I can't find the solution. Have a look at the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
  annotate("text", x = 20, y = 0.25, label = "Model R^2 = 0.4",
           parse = TRUE)
```

Have a look at the result in the picture:

[image]

What can I do to see the "=" symbol?

Comment: A useful question. I edited the code in the question to the minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem. The code as edited can be run on its own, without needing data. I get an error instead of what is shown in the bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

When using `parse = TRUE` you are telling R to convert the character string into an R expression. These expressions have a specific syntax that limits where white space is allowed and also requires that equals `=` sign to be "protected". One way of achieving this is shown bellow.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
  theme_classic() +
  annotate("text", x = 20, y = 0.25, label = "Model~~R^2~`=`~0.4",
           parse = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now it is working, and I understand the problem!